# How to reach application stability

Tags: monitoring, docker-swarm

We’ve created some kind of python monitoring app that performs health-check of our system once in 10 minutes and sends text alarms to our engineers (via jabber/slack) if something went wrong.
Are there any best practices we can introduce to be sure monitoring works even if server it’s hosted on is down? Any good books/online materials covering stability topic? First idea was to use docker swarm and multiple servers (just because I know it exists and seems to solve the problem) but maybe there’re way better solutions I’m not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best practice would be to build your SRE stack out of off the shelf rather than home grown components.

prometheus, alertmanager and so on.

Then you want your actual alerting infrastructure to be cloud hosted - PagerDuty for example.
And use something like Pingdom as an external check that your crucial infrastructure is operating.